# How to do this in a new window?

Tags: javascript

```
location.href = "/search.php?key=" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "&type=" + type;
```

I want to reserve the original window ,how to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.open("/search.php?key=" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "&type=" + type)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open("/search.php?key=" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "&type=" + type);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `window.open` method, and specify `_blank` as target:

```
var url = '/search.php?key=' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '&type=' + type;
window.open(url, '_blank');
```